# 2D Movement Bug in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a 2D Space Shooter game in Unity but stumbled upon a bug that needs fixing. I'm using Unity 2021.1.0f1 and the new Input System in Unity and I'm trying to implement movement for my character. When I press the WASD keys, my character for some reason moves 15 units on every press. I don't want that, I want smooth movement for my character. Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class Ship : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Keyboard _keyboard = Keyboard.current;

    [SerializeField] private float speed = 0.25f;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject projectile;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (speed == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Please assign a a value to \"speed\".");
        }

        if (rigidbody == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Please assign a a value to \"rigidbody\".");
        }

        if (projectile == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Please assign a a value to \"projectile\".");
        }
    }

    public void OnMove(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        Vector2 movementVector = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        Vector3 move = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0.0f) * new Vector3(movementVector.x, movementVector.y, 0.0f);

        transform.position += move * speed;
    }

    public void OnFire(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        Vector2 spawnPosition = new Vector2(transform.position.x, 0.5f);

        if (context.performed)
        {
            Instantiate(projectile, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone?

Comment: transform.position += move * speed * Time.deltaTime;

Comment: I haven't used the new input system but from your description it sounds like `OnMove` is only being called on move key down, but in addition to Majid khalili's recommendation, you should also make `OnMove` get called each frame a move input is pressed (or, even every frame, since a zeroed `movementVector` has no effect.

Comment: Didn't work. Got a **very** weird output.

Comment: Do you mean you tried multiplying by `Time.deltaTime`

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on the same project lately and I used the following code for the movement of my spaceship and it moves smoothly :

void C_Movement(){

```
  //Input controller (direction)
  float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
  float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") ;

  Vector3 directionX = new Vector3(horizontalInput,0,0) ;
  transform.Translate(directionX* Time.deltaTime * 13) ;

  Vector3 directionY = new Vector3(0,verticalInput,0) ;
  transform.Translate(directionY* Time.deltaTime * 13) ;

}
```

Comment: This uses the old Unity Input System, but in my project I'm using the New Unity Input System. Sorry, but this didn't help.